# Node/Express — req.query.token // ER_PARSE_ERROR

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm trying to parse a URL in an Express backend but when I go to a url like http://localhost:5000/reset-password?token=Wp+JCrZGAHEbDgyC4BExpWkX17Y0eurUZMu0zmu7J/5S3ChuRXoi3qdBFtdt6UlOJvMlsR4dOlMwlUS/u9UbWQ==&email=test@test.com I get error: ER_PARSE_ERROR.

`Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(email,token) VALUES ('test@test.com', 'Wp JCrZGAHEbDgyC4BExpWkX' at  line 1`

My code:

```
router.get('/reset-password', function(req, res, next) {
  const token = req.query.token;
  const email = req.query.email;
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM resettoken(email,token) VALUES (?, ?)', [email, token], function(err, result) {
if (err) throw err;
```

Where have I gone wrong? Why req.query.token takes only part of token 'Wp JCrZGAHEbDgyC4BExpWkX' instead of 'Wp+JCrZGAHEbDgyC4BExpWkX17Y0eurUZMu0zmu7J/5S3ChuRXoi3qdBFtdt6UlOJvMlsR4dOlMwlUS/u9UbWQ=='

Comment: Your SELECT syntax isn't right. It would be closer to right if it were an INSERT. Beyond that it's hard to guess from your question what you hope to do.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to compare token in db with link token, but I get only Er_Parse_Error

Answer (score 0):

Problem was with connection.query, right one is:

```
connection.query('SELECT * FROM resettoken WHERE email = ? AND token = ?', [email, token], functi...
```